# how to use JAX Abstract value in jnp.arrange

Tags: python, jax

I'm facing an issue that I can't resolve. Here's my function

```
@jax.jit
def gaussian_shape5(i,j,DF):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.


    """

   sigma=DF[i,j]
   size= jnp.int16(2* (3* jnp.ceil(sigma))+1)
   sigma_sqrt= 2*(sigma**2)
   x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor((size-1) / 2)
   exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (sigma_sqrt))
   exponent = (exponent * exponent[:,jnp.newaxis])/ jnp.sum(exponent)
   return exponent
```

In this function, I'm encountering a problem with the value of size :

```
ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected:     Traced<ShapedArray(int16[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=4/0)>
It arose in the jnp.arange argument 'stop'
```

I've tried modifying the code by calculating size externally and using:

```
@partial(jax.jit,static_argnums=3)
def gaussian_shape5(i,j,DF,size):
    """
    Generate a Gaussian shape.


    """

   sigma=DF[i,j]
   sigma_sqrt= 2*(sigma**2)
   x = jnp.arange(0, size) - jnp.floor((size-1) / 2)
   exponent = jnp.exp(-(x ** 2) / (sigma_sqrt))
   exponent = (exponent * exponent[:,jnp.newaxis])/ jnp.sum(exponent)
   return exponent
```

I'm encountering this error:

```
ValueError: Non-hashable static arguments are not supported, as this can lead to unexpected cache-misses. Static argument (index 3) of type <class 'jax._src.interpreters.partial_eval.DynamicJaxprTracer'> for function gaussian_shape5 is non-hashable.
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're passing a scalar-shaped array to the `size` argument. If you instead cast the size to an integer, it should work:

```py
DF = jnp.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
gaussian_shape5(0, 1, DF, size=int(DF[0, 1]))
# Array([[1.]], dtype=float32)
```

That said, if you're doing this within some other dynamic construct (like a `fori_loop` or `while_loop`, or a function wrapped in `jit` or `vmap`), this won't work because `DF[0, 1]` is not a static integer.

In this case, what your code is expressing is not possible to execute in JAX, because you are constructing a dynamically-shaped array. See See [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes) for some discussion of this.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the issue still persists. The function gaussianshape5 is called within a 2 'foriloop' loop  for I and j with a decorator (jax.jit).

Comment: In that case, you're attempting to create a dynamically-shaped array, which is not possible in JAX. If you want to use `fori_loop`, you'll have to re-express your algorithm in terms of statically-shaped arrays. See [JAX Sharp Bits: Dynamic Shapes](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Common_Gotchas_in_JAX.html#dynamic-shapes) for some discussion of this.